# TextOverflow.ellipsis does not show the 3 dots Flutter-Web

Tags: text, widget, overflow, flutter-web, ellipsis

In my project, when I use the overflow property with the value Textoverflow.ellipsis, it is displayed as follows:

[Main project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBLux.png)

On the other hand, in a completely new project, I do the same test and it is displayed correctly:

[Test project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPHD7.png)

I don't know what it could be, in the 2 projects, I have UTF-8 configured and the pubspec.yaml are the same, there is no difference.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey there, could you share a reproduction sample of your code? Perhaps a repo?

Comment: The problem is that if i create a new proejct and try to repro it just works, so I was wondering if someone knew what could it be.

Comment: It would help to have more context behind what's going on